# TypeError: Cannot set property window of #<Window> which has only a getter --NextJs 12.2.2

Tags: javascript, next.js

I recently upgraded a NextJs project from ver 12.1.6 to the latest 12.2.2. Upon running npm run dev, the browser throws the following error on a 3rd party lib that helps with the SplitText Effect.

```
"TypeError: Cannot set property window of #<Window> which has only a getter"
```

The code that is causing the error:

```
!(function (D, u) {
  "object" == typeof exports && "undefined" != typeof module
    ? u(exports)
    : "function" == typeof define && define.amd
    ? define(["exports"], u)
    : u(((D = D || self).window = D.window || {}));
})(this, function (e) {
...
```

I've never personally dealt with getter and setter before, so I'm having a hard time understanding the above code and how to fix the issue. I wonder if anyone has ever encountered a similar issue and has a working solution?

Comment: looks like a common way to export a module. it seems the script is being executed in strict mode and trying to reassign `window.window`. what exact library is it?

Comment: @don_aman It's SplitText3 from gsap. I've already set reactStrictMode to false, but the problem still exists. What's interesting is that everything worked fine before the upgrade.

Comment: @don_aman oh I think i misunderstood your comment about Strict Mode, and I do notice the script has the “use strict” directive in it, maybe that’s what’s causing the issue.

Comment: that's right, the `"use strict"` directive generally is included by the bundler, which I think is Webpack for Next.js. if it doesn't hurt to alter the library, try changing `: u(((D = D || self).window = D.window || {}));` with `: u("undefined" != typeof (D = D || self).window ? D.window : (D.window = {}));`

Comment: @don_aman Thanks for your suggestions, I tried removing "use strict" directive, and the problem still proceeds, however, when I tried replacing the code snippet you suggested, it did solve the original problem, but it created a different error "TypeError: splitText_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default is not a constructor". I'm thinking this might be a lib specific problem, I might have to take it to the Gsap form and see if they have a fix for it. But thank you for your reply! much appreciated!